# Saving location information to a unique user id in database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, annotations, location

In my application the user has an option which allows their locations to be saved when they hit a button. At the minute the lat and lng of their locations is saved to my database, however it is not saved under their unique id as show in my [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7XKq.png).

I am not sure what I need to add or change so that these "personal locations" are saved as a branch under their own personal user identification. This will allow me to load up their saved locations to a specific user later on.

I would appreciate any and all help as I am really stuck! Below is my code relating to this questions. Thanks!

```
 //User can save their location
@IBAction func findUserLocationAndDropPin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userLocationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    let pinForUserLocation = MGLPointAnnotation()

    pinForUserLocation.coordinate = userLocationCoordinates

    pinForUserLocation.title = ""
    pinForUserLocation.subtitle = ""

    mapView.addAnnotation(pinForUserLocation)
    mapView.showAnnotations([pinForUserLocation], animated: true)

    //When the user clicks the button, send the CLLocation Coordinate 2D make to firebase against their user ID

    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

    let locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("personalLocations").child(uid).childByAutoId()

    locationsRef.setValue(["lat": locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude, "lng": locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude])

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language/syntax, but in this line: `let locationsRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child("personalLocations").child(uid).childByAutoId()` it seems you should have `.child("users").child("uid").child(personalLocations).` instead of `.child("users").child("personalLocations").child(uid)`

Comment: Thanks very much @Forklift I should have spotted that!

Comment: No problem. One thing to help you find things like that is instead of seeking to find "why isn't it doing what I want it to?" ask "why is it doing what it is doing?" Asking that question after looking at your picture, I was able to quickly spot your problem without knowing the technology or syntax.

Comment: Great tip Forklift, I will keep that in mind